# How can I make the output start to be calculated after certain time?

Tags: programming, output

Good day,

I have a problem.

I want to run two matrix based on time given. I used TimeUsed.

given, matrix a and b;

```
a={{g*t, 2}, {3, 4}}
b={{3, 4}, {5, h*t}}
```

I use For loop:

```
g=Pi;
h=3 Pi/2;
b={{3, 4}, {5, h*t}};
For[t = 0, t < 15, t++, a = {{g*t, 2}, {3, 4}}; output1 = a^2; If[t> 
10, d = a . b; output2 = d^2]; Print[output1]; Print[output2];t = t + TimeUsed[]]
```

My problem is, I want the value of output d listed when t>10 (I mean, it will be start calculated after t>10 not from beginning i.e t=0).

How can I make the process become like that?

Please help me. Thank you.

Comment: maybe Pause function will help.

Comment: i already read the Pause function but it cannot be used in TimeUsed

Comment: I still don't know what you want to achieve. Can you give a desired output effect?

Comment: I want the output d appear after t>30